# Time complexity of nested 'For loop' with different conditions

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, frequency-analysis

Need help understanding how the second loop is executed, I know for the second loop you would multiply by the first loop. First I count the number of instructions and then apply big-oh notation. This is my approach:  would j=2*n be executed 2n times, j>=1 n+1, and j-- n times? New to big-oh notation and can't seem to find a list of 'for loops' examples anywhere, would love the feedback and information on where to practice more.

```
acc=10 \\ 1 

for(i=5;i<=n/2;i++) \\ 1+n/2+n = (1+3n/2)

   for(j=2*n; j>=1; j--) \\ (1+3n/2)(2n+n+1+n)

       acc -= j + acc++; \\ (1+1+1) (2n+n+1+n)
```

Comment: What are those double backslashes? Are they supposed to be comments `//`?

Comment: `j=2*n` is executed once; `j>=1` is executed 2*n+1 times, `j--` is executed 2*n times. But you don't need to be that precise with the counting. k*n is a linear complexity, i.e. O(n).

Comment: complexity used to count comparaisons, not operations. If you want to count operations, then you use wrong factor for inner loops, you should multiply by number of loop, not by number of instruction on the line of the loop (so `n/2 - 5` instead of `1+3n/2`).

Answer (score 2):

Constant factors do not matter for asymptotic complexity. The inner loop starts at `2*n` and counts down till `1`. It has `O(n)` iterations. The outer loop starts at `5` and counts up till `n/2`. It has `O(n)` iterations. In total the nested loop is `O(n*n)`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that constant factors do not matter, but I was trying to count the primitive operations executed and then use big-oh notation to remove constants and lower order terms.  Sorry I apologize I should have clarified in the very beginning. Which why I wanted to see if I got the count of operations correct on each statement?

Comment: @aron_C sorry, but the only count in your comments I do understand is `(1+1+1)` for a constant count of operations in the inner loop body, the rest is unclear. I am counting operations to arrive at `O(n*n)` btw